# javascript addEventListener registers previous changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a modal for file uploading. It is working fine on the first try then on the second it uploads the image twice, three times on the third attempt and so on. It is probably something basic but I don't know how to prevent this.

Basically what's causing my problem is behaviour of event listener:

```
document.getElementById('upfile').addEventListener('change', askForTags, false);
```

The test case is here: http://jsfiddle.net/mMJes/2/

Alert will show once on the first upload then twice etc. How to stop that behaviour?

Full code:

```
document.getElementById('upfile').addEventListener('change', askForTags, false);

function askForTags(evt) {

    $('.add-tags-section').show();

    $("#submit-tags").click(function () {
        tags = $('#add-tags-input').val();
        $('.add-tags-section').hide();
        handleFileSelect(evt);
    });
}

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    alert('here');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're binding yet another identical `click` event handler every time `askForTags` is invoked. Only bind one click handler, and it'll work.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/FvpUe/

```
document.getElementById('upfile').addEventListener('change', askForTags, false);

function askForTags(evt) {
    $('.add-tags-section').show();
}

$("#submit-tags").click(function () {
    tags = $('#add-tags-input').val();
    $('.add-tags-section').hide();
    handleFileSelect(evt);
});

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    alert('here');
}
```

Comment: Thanks but doing it this way we are passing different event to handleFileSelect(evt). There are no files attached to this event and I'm using  FileReader to convert selected image to binary, so I can't use that. There was different answer here which I would accept but it got deleted quickly. Demo of it: http://jsfiddle.net/kcFZn/

Comment: @user1590158: Aren't the files available directly from the `input type="file"` element?

Comment: ...or via the event object when you submit the form? It would seem very odd to have to bind/unbind a click handler like that.